# BigCouch IDs and Backup data on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, bigcouch

I have a few questions about BigCouch that i'm interesting getting answers before start using it.

- Do I need to choose my shard key carefully or can just use an auto-generated GUID? I start with a single server with 1 replication, but I want to be ready when I need to add another shard
- Any GUI for managing the cluster like CouchBase have, something similar to administer the DB
- How can I backup the data when hosting BigCouch on EC2 (ie. snapshots)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no started to use BigCouch yet and it looks like you need some features that are available out of the box in Couchbase (auto-sharding, administration console ...)

Why no going on Couchbase ?